# What is/are the equivelant openssl command(s) to do the following in Java code

Tags: java, openssl

Hi I have the following java code.

What is the Openssl commands equivalent. I want to be able to run from OS command line.

This is what i think the openssl command equivalent is...  but I am not entirely sure.

> openssl dgst -sha256 -sign my_private.key -out /tmp/sign.sha256 codeTosign.txt

When i try both and then compare them 
sign.sha256 
compare to output from 
System.out.println("Signature="+base64Signature);

they are not equal / do not match.

```
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

public class SHA256RSA {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String input = "sample input";

    // Not a real private key! Replace with your private key!
    String strPk = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvwIBADANBgkqhkiG9"
            + "w0BAQEFAASCBKkwggSlAgEAAoIBAQDJUGqaRB11KjxQ\nKHDeG"
            + "........................................................"
            + "Ldt0hAPNl4QKYWCfJm\nNf7Afqaa/RZq0+y/36v83NGENQ==\n" 
            + "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";

    String base64Signature = signSHA256RSA(input,strPk);
    System.out.println("Signature="+base64Signature);
}

// Create base64 encoded signature using SHA256/RSA.
private static String signSHA256RSA(String input, String strPk) throws Exception {
    // Remove markers and new line characters in private key
    String realPK = strPk.replaceAll("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
                         .replaceAll("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
                         .replaceAll("\n", "");

    byte[] b1 = Base64.getDecoder().decode(realPK);
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(b1);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

    Signature privateSignature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
    privateSignature.initSign(kf.generatePrivate(spec));
    privateSignature.update(input.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    byte[] s = privateSignature.sign();
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(s);
}
```

}
references : https://www.quickprogrammingtips.com/java/how-to-create-sha256-rsa-signature-using-java.html

Comment: You're showing `openssl` commands while asking for `openssl` commands. In what way are the commands not working?

Comment: I want to be able to run from linux command line.  Not from within java  app.

Comment: So run the `openssl` command you showed.

Comment: When i execute both - the contents of "s" do not match  /tmp/sign.sha256.
or are they in the wrong format ?

Comment: Then edit the question and say what is wrong. In my first comment I asked you *"In what way are the commands not working?"* because the question text doesn't say anything about that.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the difference in input (an in-memory variable versus file contents, which I assume you have made *exactly* the same), your Java code **base64** encodes the result (and sticks `Signature=` on the front) but `openssl dgst -sign` does not.

The simplest way is to have Java write the binary (without encoding it), but then you have to compare in binary, for example `cmp` on Unix or `fc /b` on Windows; a visual or text-mode comparison will not give reliable results.

You can instead base64-encode the OpenSSL output, but be careful: there are many base64 encoding schemes, which often produce *similar but not identical* output, thus the output may compare unequal even when the signatures are the same (see below). In particular if that `Base64` is Java8+ `java.util.Base64` then the default 'basic' encoder uses the classic PEM/MIME alphabet and no line terminators. If you pipe the output of `openssl dgst -sign` into `openssl base64` it defaults to the same alphabet but line terminators every 64 characters. If you use `openssl base64 -A` it should suppress the line terminators. If you have other base64-encoding programs on your system, they may (each) behave differently. If you really want the `Signature=` on the front, use any appropriate text-manipulation program like `sed awk perl` or even most shells on Unix.

Aside: you should not assume you can verify a signature by comparing it to a newly-generated one. The scheme used here, RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 aka 'classic type 01', happens to be deterministic, and comparing happens to work, but many other digital signature schemes are not deterministic. The correct way to verify a signature is to apply the verification process defined by the signature scheme. For examples, Java `Signature.initVerify(pubkeyobj), update(databuf), verify(signaturebuf)` or OpenSSL commandline `dgst -$hash <datafile -verify pubkeyfile -signature file` .

Comment: Thanks every one for help. 
The ultimate problem i had in the end was when i copied an pasted string 
"sample input" it was appending a "\n".
When this was removed. The output of the openssl command matched the output of the java snippet.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks every one for help. 
The ultimate problem i had in the end was when i copied an pasted string 
"sample input" it was appending a "\n".
When this was removed. The output of the openssl command matched the output of the java snippet.

Thanks all.